# gnome 3.28 disable ready/completed pop-up

Tags: gnome3, notifications

in RHEL 7.5, or 7.6 where I am using GNOME classic 3.28,

- I run a tar command in a terminal window which takes a few seconds, when finished a popup happens saying *command completed*
- and other times when I right click and do new terminal, the terminal window shows up almost immediately, but i also get a popup saying *terminal window is ready*

I don't like those popups in gnome telling me what I already know, is there a way to disable that?

Comment: These are not related: the 1st thing has nothing to do with gnome, it's something specific to your distro (most likely [this](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda/issues/154) or [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/notifies-terminal-commands-completed-undistract-me.html)); the 2nd one is indeed gnome related but there's not much you can do because gnome thinks your window was launched in the background (behind other windows) so it notifies you about it... I'd call it a normal gnome bug - there's hundreds of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using gnome-session 3.28.1-10.0.1.el8 and have a Notifications page in Settings that allows me to turn off all notifications or just those for a particular application. Turning them all off seems to have prevented the annoying completion messages.

Comment: thanks,  running rhel 7.9 now; I see there is the `Notification Popups`  in Settings having **on** or **off** .  And it seems to be a per user setting.